# Using Struts2 Tags in Enterprise Application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have created an enterprise application with an EJB module. But I haven't created a Web war yet.

Then I created a Struts2 web, and add it into the enterprise application.

It's ok. If I use the HTML Tag, but when I use Struts2 tag it throw an exception:

Here:

**"HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error**

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException:**

The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.

This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter.

Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
root cause

The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter.

Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.

- [unknown location]
  note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source **Edition 4.0 logs**.HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException:**

The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.

This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
root cause

The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter.

Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.

- [unknown location]
  note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly says that

> This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated
>   filter

this means that you have a JSP and struts tags inside it, but this JSP is not used by the filter, because it could be a welcome file, i.e. `index.jsp`, error code file, i.e. `404.jsp`, configured in the `web.xml`.

These resources are handled by the web server before any filter or servlet mapped to the resource is being involved.

Usually welcome files contain a redirect code to a valid action which then dispatches a JSP that can have Struts tags.

Don't use JSPs directly in your application, use actions instead.

Comment: Could you give me a sample. Thank you

Comment: I still dont know how to figured it out :(
My problem is how to use struts2 tags in Enterprise Application.

Comment: Use an action that returns a dispatcher result, it could be classless action (in this case a default action class is used), if you are using struts tags then you need some properties from the value stack and you add a class to the action to initialize those properties. If you return your JSP as a result it will use a value stack and action which is on top of it to render properties used by the struts tags.

Comment: You mean I have to push it do an action first? I really need to solve this problem now because I'm doing my project and I don't have to must time left :(

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying here. I have told you what to do. Either you do it or not I have nothing to add.

Comment: Ok. I will try again. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly says the problem.

For `Struts` tags to get resolved, you need to initiliazes the `Struts Filter class` via `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[More information](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html)

Comment: But where I have to put the Struts Dispatcher Servlet to?
At the Enterprice or the EJB Module

Comment: which could mean the request is not going via Struts filter, make sure that the url pattern is correctly set up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it :

1 - Make sure your welcome file in the web.xml isn't the one that has the struts tags.

So create a page index.jsp, add it to web.xml as follow :

```
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>/vues/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

And the index.jsp should only have a code to redirect the user to your actual index page that has the struts tags.

```
<%
     response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath()) + "/index.action");
%>
```

index.action is an action without a class, its result is to direct you to you actual index page, so in struts.xml you'll have the following :

```
    <action name="index">
        <result>jspPages/index-logged-out.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to config the struts default filter dispatcher in the web.xml

Comment: it's very small information about that answer, please describe it more broadly